# Pyspark notebooks NOT being deployed in TEST environment

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I have developed pyspark notebooks in DEV environment, but those notebooks don't get deployed into TEST environment. I used followed override parameters.

azure_synapse_deploy_param_replace: true
azure_synapse_deploy_start_triggers: true

Please guide on what I am missing in main.yml file so that I can deploy the notebooks into TEST environment.

```
- name: ansible-role-azure-synapse-deploy
    #azure_synapse_name: "dev-gomwp-synapse-cvx"
    azure_synapse_name: "{{ cvx_environment_name }}-{{ cvx_mnemonic | lower }}-synapse-cvx"
    azure_synapse_linkedservice_parameter_override:
      - name: Environment
        value: "{{ cvx_environment_name }}"
    azure_synapse_deploy_param_replace: true
    azure_synapse_deploy_start_triggers: true
```